# How should I create an ImmutableArray from a Span/ReadOnlySpan?

Tags: c#

Suppose I have a method like the following:

```cs
unsafe void Convert(byte* ptr, int length)
{
    var span = new Span<byte>(ptr, length);
    var arr = ImmutableArray.CreateRange(span); // error: cannot convert from 'System.Span<byte>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<byte>'
    Use(arr);
}
```

The `CreateRange` method in the above sample is the `CreateRange<T>(IEnumerable<T>)` overload. Since Span doesn't implement any interfaces it makes sense that we can't make this call. But I am actually a bit stumped as to what to do instead. Is there some idiomatic way to create an ImmutableArray from a Span with minimal copying/allocation? (i.e. using `Span<T>.ToArray()` and then `ImmutableArray<T>.ToImmutableArray()` would not be ideal)

Would also appreciate any suggestions that involve using the pointer+length directly in some way.

Comment: Unfortunately no, as `ImmutableArray` has no `Span` constructor. You are going to have to do a double copy. But it should be pretty fast, it's only one extra allocation as `ToArray` knows the size upfront.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/22928) (as of June 2021) discussing adding APIs for this.

Until then, the issue suggests using a builder like this:

```cs
static ImmutableArray<T> ImmutableArrayFromSpan<T>(ReadOnlySpan<T> span)
{
    var builder = ImmutableArray.CreateBuilder<T>(span.Length);
    foreach (var i in span) {
        builder.Add(i);
    }
    return builder.MoveToImmutable();
}
```

Comment: This does as much copying as `.ToArray().ToImmutableArray()`, but with more overhead, and as many allocations. Personally, I'd go for the other option.

Comment: `ToArray().ToImmutableArray()` allocates an two arrays, the code in the answer only allocates one, for the builder. `MoveToImmutable` does not allocate a new array.